# Replace ConfigurationBasedServerList for all services

Tags: java, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-ribbon

With Ribbon, if you want to use a custom `ServerList` implementation instead of the default `ConfigurationBasedServerList` for a specific service, you can do it like this in the application configuration file:

```
my-service:
  ribbon:
    NIWSServerListClassName: com.myapp.MyCustomServerList
```

My issue is that I want to replace the default `ConfigurationBasedServerList` for all services I declare to use the `MyCustomServerList`.

I could just add the previous properties block for each service, but that could grow endlessly.

Is there a way to declare `MyCustomServerList` as default?

I've also tried adding this bean to my `@Configuration` class, but it only seems to work the first time I do a request:

```
@Bean
public ServerList<Server> ribbonServerList() {
    return new MyCustomServerList();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Dalston.SR1/#_customizing_the_ribbon_client

```
@RibbonClients(defaultConfiguration=MyConfig.class)

//...

class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    public ServerList<Server> ribbonServerList() {
        return new MyCustomServerList();
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, but now I'd like to inject a `IClientConfig` to be able to instantiate the `ServerList` with it: `public ServerList<Server> ribbonServerList(IClientConfig config) {
        return new MyCustomServerList(config);
    }`. Is this possible? Spring doesn't find any bean that matches `IClientConfig` if I do it right away.

Comment: It should. Don't put `@Configuration` on `MyConfig` or exclude it from component scanning.